# Как произвести запрос выборки и целого числа, и числа с плавающей точкой(запятой) из одного столбца в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

В столбце the_area есть числа как целые, так и с плавающей запятой. Сам тип данных данного столбика естественно char. Поскольку я выбираю данные числа используя регулярные выражения(то есть сначала нахожу целые числа, потом нахожу числа с плавающей запятой), то мне нужно их вывести вместе при запросе SELECT.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вывести вместе через AND естественно не получится, ибо так же в запросе есть и другие элементы, которые нужно вывести.

```
SELECT * FROM property
    WHERE city = 'Витебск'
    AND rooms = 1
    AND substring(REPLACE(the_area, ',', '.') from '\/(\w\d..)(\/.*)')::real >= 10
    AND substring(the_area from '\/(\w\d)(\/.*)')::real >= 10;
```

Вопрос. Как можно поступить, чтобы вывести одновременно и целые числа, и числа с плавающей запятой?

Comment: Замените скриншот на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скрипты. Покажите требуемый ответ для этих данных.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь, что-то затупил. В общем нужно просто было поправить регулярное выражение.

```
SELECT * FROM property
    WHERE city = 'Витебск'
    AND rooms = 1
    AND substring(REPLACE(the_area, ',', '.') from '\/(.*)(\/.*)')::real >= 10;
```